# IIS - Trying to access DLL file with parameter from webbrowser is getting 404 Not Found

Tags: iis, dll

I'm able to access a DLL file which is stored at my local server's `inetpub/wwwroot/myprogram/` directory with below URL (from webbrowser)

```
   http://localserver.com/myprogram/program.DLL
```

But, i want to access this DLL file with a parameter from webbrowser such as

```
   http://localserver.com/myprogram/program.DLL/DL?
```

/DL? parameter will return a license text instead of whole DLL file. But I'm getting "404 not found" error into webbrowser when i add this parameter

how can i allow access this DLL with /DL? parameter ( from IIS Manager )

Thanks Inadvance

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Read IIS log files to see what kind of 404 you hit.

Comment: 404 indicate that the requested file is not available. make sure that parameter and the use are correct and the file is available at the place and iis user has enough permission to access it.

Comment: Thanks for answers, i can access DLL file with ```   http://localserver.com/myprogram/program.DLL``` there is no access problem i think. Problem is /DL? parameter. This parameter causing 404 error

Comment: do you have any link which lists some parameter and its usage?  look like the dl parameter has some issues. are you sure the dl parameter is used for getting the license text?